# Do inheritances automatically get inherited by all child classes in C#

Tags: c#

Something I was just testing with a simple using() statement.

Got 2 classes: Child and Parent

```
public class Parent : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
       // disposing stuff
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
       // disposing stuff
    }
}
```

Now when I start using Using() statements:

```
using(Parent = new Parent()){}
```

Dispose does get called for Parent

```
using(Child = new Child()){}
```

Dispose isn't called

Unless I specifically add:

```
public class Child : Parent, IDisposable
```

Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Which `Dispose`? If there is a `Dispose` in `Child` then either the one in `Parent` needs to be `virtual` or `Child` needs to specify that it also implements `Dispose`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so that we may look at what else might be relevant. Merely fleshing out the code in your question so that it compiles shows that the dispose method is indeed called, so something is making you believe it isn't.

Comment: @DStanley I just added some more code. How does one specify that it should use the parents Dispose method?

Comment: It should use Parent.Dispose in this case. You will get a warning on Child.Dispose about it hiding the inherited member, but this has no bearing on the outcome.

Comment: @StevenSpieler See my answer, either have `Child` implement `IDisposable` or make `Dispose` `virtual` in the parent and an `override` in the child.

Comment: Just a note that the `:` in `Parent : IDisposable` is "implements", not "inherits", like it is in "Child : Parent".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your `Dispose` method is not `virtual` and you also have a `Dispose` method in `Child`. The problem is that when you cast `Child` to `IDisposable` (which `using` does implicitly), then the compiler is binding to the `Dispose` method in `Parent`, since that's the type that implements `IDisposable`. If `Dispose` were `virtual`, then at runtime the binder would look for an override of `Dispose` in the `Child` class and call that.

```
public class Parent : IDisposable
{
    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Disposed");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Child Disposed");
    }
}
```

Or, if `Child` implements `IDisposable` (which seems redundant), then the cast to `IDisposable` would bind to the `Dispose` method on `Child` instead of `Parent`.

```
public class Parent : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Disposed");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Child Disposed");
    }
}
```

Note that in either case you should call the parent's `Dispose` method from the child `Dispose` method, whether you are overriding or implementing the interface yourself. That way you ensure that any unmanaged resources held by the parent class get disposed as well.

```
public override void Dispose()
{
    Console.WriteLine("In Child Disposed");
    base.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this explanation! So your recommendation would be to add a New Void Dispose() that uses base.Dispose()?

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion either way - the .NET framework (especially `Component` classes) tends to override the base dispose method (calling the base method afterwards) instead of re-implementing the interface. That would be cleaner if you were implementing a large interface and only changing one method. Since `Dispose` is only one method, re-implementing is not much different.